# If-else statement with radio buttons and a for loop

Tags: c#, undeclared-identifier

I've gotten an issue that keeps happening and I'm unsure what the problem is. I need to create a program in Microsoft Visual studio where radioButton1 is for finding the sum of consecutive numbers and radioButton2 is for finding the factorial of a number.

There will be three buttons, one for FOR loop, one for WHILE loop, and one for DO-WHILE loop. I'm working on the FOR button.

What I'm trying to do is by making a selection, then pressing one of the buttons, it'll find the answer using the loop clicked in a Message box.

This is what I've gotten so far:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  if ((radioButton1.Checked == true) && (radioButton2.Checked == false))
  {
    int sum = 0;
    int number = int.Parse(numericUpDown1.Value.ToString());
    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
    {
      sum = sum + i;
      MessageBox.Show("The sum of the consecutive numbers leading up to " + number + " is " + sum + ".");
    }
    MessageBox.Show("The sum of the consecutive numbers leading up to " + number + " is " + sum + ".");
  }
  else if ((radioButton2.Checked == true) && (radioButton1.Checked == false))
  {
    int product = 1;
    int number = int.Parse(numericUpDown1.Value.ToString());
    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
    {
      product *= i;
      MessageBox.Show("The factorial of the numbers leading up to " + number + " is " + product + ".");
    }
    MessageBox.Show("The factorial of the numbers leading up to " + number + " is " + product + ".");
  }
  else
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid");
  }
}
```

I keep receiving this message:

"'Lab5'does not contain a definition for 'radioButton2.CheckedChanged' and no extension method 'radioButton2.CheckChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'Lab5' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)."

And I honestly have no idea what that means.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I want to keep it in an if-else statement simply because I don't want the message box for radioButton1 to pop up when radioButton2 is selected.

Comment: Which line of your above code does that error message refer to? What it means is basically that somewhere, you have a method call that looks like `Lab5.CheckedChanged(...)`, but `Lab5` (whatever that is) does not have a `CheckedChanged` method.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is thrown at the client code of the aspx file. Can you please show us your HTML code with the `RadioButton` tag?

Comment: You should give your controls names

Comment: @LinusCaldwell: Not saying you're wrong, but where do you see this is ASP.NET? Looks like WinForms to me ...

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, why don't you if I'm obviously wrong? ;-) Yeah, `MessageBox.Show()` could have given me a hint, but... :-D nevermind. +1

Comment: "if(foo == true)" is a longer and less readable equivalent of "if(foo)" and if(foo == false) is the same as if(!foo)

Answer (score 1):

You have probably inadvertently added a handler to that radio button (e.g. by double clicking it in the designer) and then removed it. When the solution is building, it is looking for that function but can't find it.

Check Lab5.Designer.cs for the radioButton2 code. It will look something like this:

```
 this.radioButton1.AutoSize = true;
 this.radioButton1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(102, 162);
 this.radioButton1.Name = "radioButton1";
 this.radioButton1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(85, 17);
 this.radioButton1.TabIndex = 1;
 this.radioButton1.TabStop = true;
 this.radioButton1.Text = "radioButton1";
 this.radioButton1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
 this.radioButton1.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.radioButton1_CheckedChanged); /* THis is the offending line! */
```

That last line is trying to add an event handler referencing a non-existant method. You can either remove it here.

Also, when the program builds, you should be able to double-click on the compile error and the IDE will take you to the source of the problem.

Comment: This really helped a lot! It did work after that so thank you!

Comment: @KJohns Cool. Yeah, it's easy to accidentally add event handlers by double-clicking in the designer. If that solved all your problems, feel free to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a homework. Either way, you need to implement a handler for your radio buttons for the event CheckChanged. Also, if you put those radio buttons in a group, either one can be checked and in the checkchanged event you should populate some functionMode or something. Example, when RadioButton1 is checked, you should store a variable that'll contain which formula to apply, on the other one checked you should change that. And in the button submit event, use that variable to see the current mode and apply that formula.